# The Grand Staff in Musixtex (with letters inside head notes)

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to display the Grand Staff in Musixtex with letters inside head notes, the starting code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras



\begin{document}
The grand staff with letters inside head notes:

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    \sepbarrules
    %\curlybrackets{12}
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \songtop{2}
    \songbottom{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece%
    \notes\wh{GHIJKLMNa}& \wh{*********efghijklm}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output is as follow (note that is needed to enable the curly brackets and the letter names inside the notes):
[image: expected]

Comment: Your songtop and songbottom override the curlybracket. If this is about readability: why don't you just use the letters as charnotes? In Largemusicsize you can use the normallettersize, putting the letter always one note lower than the name suggests. The 'notes' with a letter inside do not look like normal notes, so pedagogically they do not add anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the font size has been reduced, but the centering dissapeared... It is needed to correct it, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
    
\usepackage{musixtex} 

% ~~~ a labeled note ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\nla[2]{\raisebox{-1.0pt}{\roffset{.35}{\zcharnote{#1}{\tiny{#2}}}}\wh{#1}}
\newcommand\nl[1]{\nla{#1}{x}}% reusing aboves macro to just place an "x"
  
\begin{document}
The grand staff with letters inside head notes:

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    \sepbarrules
    %\curlybrackets{12}
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \songtop{2}
    \songbottom{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \font\A=phvb8t at 3pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
    %\notes\wh{GHIJKLMNa}& \wh{*********efghijklm}\en
    \notes\nla{G}{\A G}\nla{H}{\A A}\nla{I}{\A B}\nla{J}{\A C}\nla{K}{\A D}\nla{L}{\A E}\nla{M}{\A F}\nla{N}{\A G}\nla{a}{\A A}& 
    \wh{*********}\nla{e}{\A E}\nla{f}{\A F}\nla{g}{\A G}\nla{h}{\A A}\nla{i}{\A B}\nla{j}{\A C}\nla{k}{\A D}\nla{l}{\A E}\nla{m}{\A F}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow (note that the letter notes now are centered):

[image: solved]

Comment: Great. Glad, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as an overlay of:

- quarter notes
- a circle filled with white
- a letter text inside the circle.

To overlay use the box-trick with width 0pt. Overlay e.g. by using tikz. Perhaps using `\savebox` can be useful.

However, I wonder if your request really results in good read-ability, because everything will tend to be comparably small. Visual effects will overlap, i.e. certain combinations of fill and linewidth will appear to be less readable.

If you just want to introduce a few scales, drawing both staffs and notes with tikz might be the better and more flexible approach.

---

Just to give you a few more ideas, to show you both possibilites and side effects.

1. Macro `\nl (1 par)` prints an "x" over the `\wh`, while `\nla (2 par)` prints some letter over `\wh`. As `\nl` is a special case of `\nla`, it just reuses the code.

---

```
% ~~~ a labeled note ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \newcommand\nla[2]{\raisebox{-2pt}{\zcharnote{#1}{#2}}\wh{#1}}
    \newcommand\nl[1]{\nla{#1}{x}}% reusing aboves macro to just place an "x"
     ...
    
    %    \notes\wh{GHIJKLMNa}& \wh{*********efghijklm}\en
        \notes\nla{G}{G}\nla{H}{A}\nla{I}{B}\nl{J}\nl{K}\nl{L}\nl{M}\nl{N}\nl{a}& \wh{*********}\nl{e}\nl{f}\nl{g}\nl{h}\nl{i}\nl{j}\nl{k}\nl{l}\nl{m}\en
     ...
```

[image: labeled notes]

2. However, if you follow the route of replacing notes from musixtex, which are just suitable glyphs/characters anyway, you can pick interesting combinations from [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). // E.g. you could pick one of the various ovals or ellipses available to replace the "note". You could try e.g. `\textcircled{A}` from the semitrans package. Or reuse some lilypond glyphs. And so on. // However, fontsizes will be a crucial point. And again, it may not end up as readable as you wanted.
3. You could also perceive your labeled note as a thick left-brace, a character and a thick right brace composition. Put inside a macro may be fine with adjusted fontsizes. But then you probably are more on a tikz-route, which gives you even better opportunities.